# I want to run the Java program under Android in shell. Why did the program quit when I created the thread?

Tags: java, android, shell

I want to run the Java program under Android in shell. Why did the program quit when I created the thread?
The sample code is as follows。

```
    package com.hw.hello;

    /**
     * Created by admin on 2017/8/15.
     */

    public class Hello {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello Android, I'm Java!!!");
            test();
        }

        private static void test() {
            System.out.println("****** test ******");
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("****** run ******");
                    super.run();
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        System.out.println("******** " + i + " ********");
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

The results are as follows：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZL06.png)

Comment: You can't run jar under android. You should have apk

Comment: Because your main function immediately returns after `test` returns. To prevent the program from finishing, you could add a `sleep` in an infinite loop but that will block your main thread indefinitely. You could also use a `ConditionVariable` to await the thread's completion

Comment: However, under the Windows, it can run normally in the process I want.Under Android shell, the output "****** test ******" is output, and then exits.

Comment: assign the thread to a variable and call `thread.join()` after you start the thread.